# Assign variable to array values and populate <td>

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following code inside a WHILE loop following a MySQL query:

```
$values=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30);

echo "<tr>
        <td class='results'>$values</td>
        <td class='results'>working query</td>
    </tr>"
```

I need the $values variable to populate and increase by 1 for each row obtained from the query.

Desired result:

```
1 | data
2 | data
3 | data
```

Comment: So you show us the desired result. And where's the result you have now?

Comment: you need a loop (link to php.net) -> http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: What is the `$values_array` for ? If only for line numbering then use the way Typoheads proposed, otherwise it needs more explanation. Also does the query needs to be **inside** the loop ? Usually you are supposed to run the query first, it returns an array of results and you loop through these to display all results.

Comment: The result I have now is "Array" where 1, 2, 3 is above. I also tried a foreach loop and the result was 30 on every row where 1, 2, 3 is above. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post the while loop, so I just assume how it looks like. You can just add a simple counter variable and increase for every row returned from DB:

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo "<tr>
        <td class='results'>$i</td>
        <td class='results'>working query</td>
    </tr>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Had the almost exact same answer... Marked it for deletion ;)

Comment: Absolutely the simplest method. Of course, I overcomplicated it! Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

use that code please

```
    <table>
    <?php

        $values=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30);
    foreach($values as $v){
    echo "<tr>
            <td class='results'>$v</td>
            <td>|</td>
            <td class='results'>working query</td>
        </tr>";

    }
    ?>
    </table>
```